# add a if clause to view page in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am working on chat box website
i created the database and connect it to the ASP.NET project then i created the model and controller using entity framework.
now am trying to display the messages in chat box view so i display the messages their but i need to add an if clause so that define if the message direction is 0 it mean that the message should display in student's div which has a specific format, else it should displayed in employee's div.
the messages table have the below structure:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    [id]        INT           NOT NULL,
    [chat_id]   INT           NULL,
    [text]      VARCHAR (250) NULL,
    [direction] BIT           NULL,
    [sort]      DATETIME      NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [messages_id_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id]),
    CONSTRAINT [messages_chats_fk] FOREIGN KEY ([chat_id]) REFERENCES chats ([id])
);
```

the code i wrote in the view page is:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        @if(item.direction == 0)
                        {
                        <div class="messages__item message-student">
                          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.text)
                       </div>
                        }
                         @else
                        <div class="messages__item message-services">
                         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.text)
                        </div>
                    }
```

but it's return an error that i can't use this condition, any one know why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not add addition `@` on `else` statement. Only one `@` per `if` and `else` statement or put them inside:

```
@{ 
  //your code
 }
```

and change foreach loop to for loop

```
@for(var i=0; i< Model.Count, i+=1)
{
    @if(Model[i].direction == 0)
    //I think it should be
    @if(Model[i].direction)

    {

    <div class="messages__item message-student">
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].text)
   </div>
    }
    else
   {
    <div class="messages__item message-services">
     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].text)
    </div>
  }                  
}
```

Comment: i still have the problem in the condition

Comment: Sorry what is the error? Try to remover @ from if too

Comment: @LightoGamer use {} for else too

Comment: this is the error "cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it's not a delegate type" i tried to replace 0 with false but still the same error

Comment: Can you post the model too pls?

Comment: @LightoGamer it seems to me that Model.direction  is bool not  number

Comment: i tried it that way and it worked if (item.direction.Value).It makes sense because the value of direction it self is bool value